# Reading cassandra simultaneously while writing

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to read cassandra table immediately while data is been inserted to the table. The table is having timestamp as one of the primary key (Not the partition key). We have a spark job reads from the kafka and writes to cassandra at every 15 secs. The server component read from the cassandra almost immediately when the spark job starts inserting the data. Since the data inserting to the cassandra and is huge we are reading the data in pages. While reading in pages ,we observed that few of the records being skipped and reaches last record.

But when we run same logic of reading the data by pages on all ready inserted data it is working fine ( no skipping of records) . Is there any way read the data in pages while data being inserted in cassandra ?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for your issue? I am facing a similar issue (not from spark but from my application). I am using consistency level as LOCAL_ONE which means read and write happens on the same datacenter and it should find the record right after the write.

Answer (score 0):

What you observe might be a result of a current [Cassandra data consistency level](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html). To make sure all data written is available to read you could use **ALL** level, but this will cause waiting for all nodes to make a change.

Comment: Thanks, i am using Statement object and passing the query with setting consistency to all `Statement statement = new SimpleStatement(query);statement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);` but still few records are missing.